# PHPMailer append email body for each recipient

Tags: php

I am using PHPMailer to send emails the normal way

```
$email = new PHPMailer();
```

I set the body to a value from my database

```
$email->Body = stripslashes(($result["message"]));
```

and then loop through a database table and add all addresses

```
$email->AddAddress($result2["email"]);
```

But I was wondering whether its possible to append to the body for each address/recipient

i know i can call `new PHPMailer();` in my loop for each recipient, but the only issue doing that is it'll stop the recipients showing in the To/CC fields

So, is it possible to just append to the body for each recipient?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to send a separate email to each recipient.

This is outside PHPMailer's area of responsibility, but that's fine as there are other libraries available to help.

good way to do that is to use templating system, which can be just PHP itself, but things like Smarty or some other.

See this for phpmailer : https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps